# How to get the Image location from URI string in terms of integer

Tags: java, android, uri

**What i have programmed**: I am using camera which selects the image from camera or gallery and returns an `Uri` on `onActivityREsult`

---

I have a Uri location which i retrieved from the camera

`String mUri="------------------";`

Now using `mUri` how can i find the image location(place where the URI is pointing to) in terms of `int`
.

Should i need to create a file with it ?, why to create a file since the image is already created ?

Comment: The URI already points to the picture (=file) in the storage, doesn't it?

Comment: Um, what does it mean for an `int` to be an "image location"? "I have a Uri location which i retrieved from the camera" -- you do not get a `Uri` from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare .... In other words, I am aware we can get the String value(Image location) from the URI that is available from camera. now suppose I have a string value(Image location on device captured by camera). how to convert back to uri .... Am i clear ?

Comment: "I am aware we can get the String value(Image location) from the URI that is available from camera" -- if you mean `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you *provide* a `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. "now suppose I have a string value(Image location on device captured by camera)" -- where did this "string value" come from? "Am i clear" -- not really. Your question could use a [mcve] showing where these values are coming from and what you are trying to do with them.

Comment: @CommonsWare .... that's a clever question. it did come from URI  :D ;) .... but I am trying to understand this method..... can i use `Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")` .......... will that form a URI back again ... i think it does ?

Comment: Well, it returns a `Uri` object. Whether that `Uri` is useful is another matter. There is no requirement for a device to have an `/sdcard` directory, for example.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **Commonsware** in one of the comments. I resolved this issue by converting back a string to URI object.

---

`Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg"))`